# Java Streams return throws error Unexpected return value

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, return, java-stream

I am quite new to Java streams and I am trying to implement a method using the streams but when I try to return the value it's throwing me the error `Unexpected return value`. I just wanted to know what am I doing wrong.

Following is the return within the `Arrays.stream` value which is throwing the error:

```
Object[] result = extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue());
Arrays.stream(result).forEach(innerExtension -> {
    return new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) innerExtension);
});
```

However, if I try to return a single value outside the `Arrays.stream` then I am able to get the first value. (As you can see I am returning the first value only `result[0]`)

```
Object[] result = extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue());
Arrays.stream(result).forEach(innerExtension -> {
    System.out.println((JAXBElement) innerExtension);
});
return new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) result[0]);
```

I want to pass the values from the `Object[] result` one by one and return the result to my calling method.

Here is the complete method that I have:

```
  private Object[] extensionBuilder(Map<String, Object> extensions) {
    if (extensions == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return extensions.entrySet().stream().map(extension -> {
      if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {

        // return new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class,
        //    (JAXBElement) extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue())[0]);

        Object[] result = extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue());
        Arrays.stream(result).forEach(innerExtension -> {
          System.out.println((JAXBElement) innerExtension);
        });
        return new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) result[0]);

      } else {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), String.class, extension.getValue().toString());
      }
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(Object[]::new);
  }
```

Here is the input given to the method:

```
{nameSpace:MyField-2={fb:My-Sub-Field-1={nameSpace:MyField-1=myValue, nameSpace:MyField-2=myValue, nameSpace:MyField-3=myValue}, nameSpace2:My-Sub-Field-2={nameSpace:MyField-4=myValue4, nameSpace:MyField-5=myValue5, nameSpace:MyField-6=myValue6}, nameSpace:MyField-7MyField-3=myValue1}, nameSpace:MyField-8=Name}
```

I am a bit confused about this for a long time now. Can someone please assist me with how to accomplish the returning concept using the stream?

Basically, I would like to return the value for every element within the `Object[] result` as of now I am able to do it only for one element but I want for each object present within the `Object[] result`

***** EDITED ON 11 May ******

Based on the response to the question I am able to do it but the response I am getting looks something like this:

```
<namespace:MainField>
    <namespace:SubField1>
        <namespace:Field1>Value1</namespace:Field1>
    </namespace:SubField1>
</namespace:MainField>
<namespace:MainField>
    <insta:SubField2>
        <insta:Field2>Value2</insta:Field2>
    </insta:SubField2>
</namespace:MainField>
<namespace:MainField>
    <namespace:SubField3>SubValue3</namespace:SubField3>
</namespace:MainField>
<namespace:MainField2>MainValue2</namespace:MainField2>
<namespace:MainField3>MainValue3</namespace:MainField3>
```

Whereas I am looking for something like this:

```
<namespace:MainField>
    <namespace:SubField1>
        <namespace:Field1>Value1</namespace:Field1>
    </namespace:SubField1>
    <insta:SubField2>
        <insta:Field2>Value2</insta:Field2>
    </insta:SubField2>
    <namespace:SubField3>SubValue3</namespace:SubField3>
</namespace:MainField>
<namespace:MainField2>MainValue2</namespace:MainField2>
<namespace:MainField3>MainValue3</namespace:MainField3>
```

This is due the `stream` which is returning the `JAXBElement` for every element within the `Object[] result` I would like to return the result after completing the looping the child stream something like this:

```
  private Object[] extensionBuilder(Map<String, Object> extensions) {
    if (extensions == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return extensions.entrySet().stream().flatMap(extension -> {
      if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        // return Stream of result transformed to JAXBElements
        return Arrays.stream(extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue())).map(innerExtension -> {
          System.out.println(innerExtension);
          return new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) innerExtension);
        });
      } else {
        return Stream.of(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), String.class, extension.getValue().toString()));
      }
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
  }
```

I tried this but this is throwing me the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement`.

Can someone please assist me on how to modify the `Java Stream` so that I can have the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to return some value from lambda passed to `forEach`. That lambda type is `Consumer<T>` and its method `accept` return type is `void` so you can't return any value from it.

If you want to return collection of objects from you method, I'd suggest to rewrite it to return `Stream`:

```java
  private Object[] extensionBuilder(Map<String, Object> extensions) {
    if (extensions == null) {
      return null;
    }
    //                        use flatMap vvvvvvv instead of map
    return extensions.entrySet().stream().flatMap(extension -> {
      if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        Object[] result = extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue());
        // return Stream of result transformed to JAXBElements
        return Arrays.stream(result).map(innerExtension -> {
          return new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) result[0]);
        });
      } else {
        // return Stream of single item
        return Stream.of(
          new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), String.class, extension.getValue().toString())
        );
      }
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
  }
```

See [Stream::flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) docs.

---

You can deal without `result` variable if you just inline it:

```java
  private Object[] extensionBuilder(Map<String, Object> extensions) {
    if (extensions == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return extensions.entrySet().stream().flatMap(extension -> {
      if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        // return Stream of result transformed to JAXBElements
        return Arrays.stream(extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue()))
          .map(innerExtension -> new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(
             new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())),
             JAXBElement.class,
             (JAXBElement) result[0]
          ));
      } else {
        return Stream.of(
          new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), String.class, extension.getValue().toString())
        );
      }
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
  }
```

But be careful it's better to come up with a better name
for this variable than just inlining it,
because it lacks readability (IMHO).

Comment: Thanks for taking time and providing your response. I am actually using this method to create the `JAXBElement` with `@XmlAnyElement(lax="true")`  for that  I need `Object[]`. Hence I am returning the `Object[]` instead of `Stream`. If possible can you guide me using the. `Object[]` as a return? Following is the documentation for `JaxBElement`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the editing and response. If I would like to do it without the result variable then how can I do it? I tried many things but I am unable to get it. I get the error java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement. I have edited my question and provided the things I have tried. If possible can you please provide some suggrestions.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 extended the answer again :)

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 not sure if it helps, you probably need to open another question with this problem.

Comment: Hi Man, Thanks a lot for the quick answer and update. Now, the duplicates are removed but I am facing one small issue if you observe the `XML` i have posted as expected output you see that `namespace:SubField1` and `namespace:SubField2` both are wrapped within a single `namespace:MainField` but based on your answer the stream is returning the value for every element of the `innerExtension` due to which its creating the `namespace:MainField` for every child element due to which I get `namespace:MainField` multiple times based on the `child` count.

Comment: (Continuing from previous comment) Is there any possibility to make the stream to return only once by building all the child elements (`innerExtension`) so that we will get only one `namespace:MainFIeld` with all of its children rather than every children (`namespace:SubField`) having its own parent?

Comment: Hi That issue I have fixed it was coming from another file. Now I have issue with streams only. Please refer to the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) for performing intermediate operations and returning the result, and then collect the result into `List`

```
Arrays.stream(result)
      .map(innerExtension -> new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) innerExtension))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And in your case if `if` condition is true you need to return List of objects and in else condition only one object. So i will recommend to return List of objects in both cases and then use `flatMap` to flatten the lists

```
private Object[] extensionBuilder(Map<String, Object> extensions) {
if (extensions == null) {
  return null;
}
return extensions.entrySet().stream().map(extension -> {
  if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {

    // return new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class,
    //    (JAXBElement) extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue())[0]);

    Object[] result = extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue());
    return Arrays.stream(result)
      .map(innerExtension -> new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) innerExtension))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

  } else {
    return Arrays.asList(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), String.class, extension.getValue().toString()));
  }})
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .toArray(Object[]::new);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I tried this and it's working and able to get the result. But the only problem is that I see that duplicate entries are being added up. I tried using the `distinct` but still able to get the duplicate entries. I guess something is getting messed up within the `streams` which is causing it to return the duplicate entries. Can you please let me know why am I getting the duplicate values instead of just single entries?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the editing and response. If I would like to do it without the result variable then how can I do it? I tried many things but I am unable to get it. I get the error java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement. I have edited my question and provided the things I have tried. If possible can you please provide some suggrestions.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` accepts a `Consumer` object (which only accepts an argument but does not return anything). But currently you are trying to return a element in the `forEach`. If you wanted to create a list of converted objects, then do as below:

```java
Object[] result = extensionBuilder((Map) extension.getValue());
Arrays.stream(result)
      .map(innerExtension -> new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) innerExtension))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

});
```

If you want to return an `Object` array instead of a `List`, replace the collect statement with `toArray`

```java
Arrays.stream(result)
      .map(innerExtension -> new JAXBElement<JAXBElement>(new QName(getCleanLabel(extension.getKey())), JAXBElement.class, (JAXBElement) innerExtension))
      .toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and responding. Actually, I would like to return `Object[]` and do not wish to create the `List`. As the calling application is expecting the return with `Object[]`. If possible can you please guide me on how to return the `Object[]`?

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 instead of the collect statement, use `toArray`. I have updated my  answer

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the editing and response. If I would like to do it without the `result` variable then how can I do it? I tried many things but I am unable to get it. I get the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement`. I have edited my question and provided the things I have tried. If possible can you please provide some suggrestions.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 Not clear on what exactly you meant by "without the `result` variable"

Comment: I have edited my question with all the details as its difficult to provide the details in the comment. If possible please once look into it and provide some suggestions if possible. Thanks.